# Outline Geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to reproduce a a scene like this one, where the geometries have an outline:

https://bernhard-42.github.io/three-cad-viewer/example.html

Neither of these two options work:

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: "#556670" });
```

So far I've not got very far, does anyone have any insight in how it is achieved?

Comment: Options: 1) https://discourse.threejs.org/t/ldraw-like-edges/17100 ; 2) https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-render-full-outlines-as-a-post-process-tutorial/22674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are rendering the scene yourself and have access to the three.js geometry, rather than tessellated triangles, then all that is required is to render lines along the edges of the geometry:

```
// Create the box geometry and material
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: '#ffc32a'});

// Create the box and add it to the scene
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

// Create the box's edges and add them to the scene
const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry);
const line = new THREE.LineSegments(
   edges, 
   new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: '#000000'})
);
scene.add(line);
```

There is no need for any custom shaders or any complex operations like that.

This will only ever produce a one pixel line because of the way the GPU works. If you need a thicker line then this can be done with `LineMaterial`, `LineSegments2` and `LineSegmentsGeometry` from examples.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lines_fat